# How to play back the recorded video after online class end in BigBlueButton

Tags: moodle, bigbluebutton

I have install plugin BigBlueButtonBN for Moodle to create an online class follow [this link](http://moodle.org/plugins/view.php?plugin=mod_bigbluebuttonbn). This online class is recorded (Webcam, slide show, chat message).
After online class end, when click to the class link, it shows "This activity is over. There is no recording yet, please come back later."

This should be showed the link to playback the recorded video. Please show me how to do this?

I use Moodle 2.3.1 and BigBlueButton 0.8 release.

Update: 
This is OK when i use Moodle 2.3.1 with BigBlueButton 0.8 **beta** version (can show the recorded video link after online class ended) but this problem occur after i upgrade to BigBlueButton 0.8 **release** version.

Answer (score 1):

[
We saw you also posted this question to our bigbluebutton-dev mailing list.  Since we've already responded to you in our mailing list, I've copied our reply below.

Since you posted the question in two forums, please respond in both places (bigbluebutton-dev and stack overflow) so readers of each community can follow the solution.
]

In BigBlueButton 0.80 there is no built-in playback of video.  See the Release Notes

http://code.google.com/p/bigbluebutton/wiki/ReleaseNotes

Can you try a recording with the test-install server to see if you get a playback.  See

url: http://test-install.blindsidenetworks.com/bigbluebutton/
salt: 8cd8ef52e8e101574e400365b55e11a6

Put the above settings in your BigBlueButtonBN configuration.   let us know if you get a recording available for playback using the above test server.

### Regards,... Fred

BigBlueButton Developer

Comment: hi Fred,
Thank you for your reply,
I have tested again using your BBB server. But the problem still the same. Please see my reply on bigbluebutton-dev mailing list with attach image for detail.(https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups#!topic/bigbluebutton-dev/U9oKAQncqj0)

Answer (score 0):

[ I'm cc'ing the answer I posted to bigbluebutton-dev for the readers here ]

We recently updated the BigBlueButtonBN integration to support Moodle 2.3.  Can you download the latest plugins for BigBlueButtonBN and RecordingsBN from

```
http://moodle.org/plugins/browse.php?list=set&id=2
```

and try it again.  We just did a test recording on the test-install server and it's working.  Please ensure the above moodle plugins are up-to-date, your testing against

```
url: http://test-install.blindsidenetworks.com/bigbluebutton/
salt: 8cd8ef52e8e101574e400365b55e11a6
```

and try doing another recording.  You should see your meeting appear in RecordingsBN.  If so, then change the URL and salt (shared secret) to point to your BigBlueButton server.

If you don't see a recording appear, please post the output of

```
sudo bbb-conf --clean
sudo bbb-conf --check
```

to bigbluebutton-dev and we'll see what's happening with the recording.

### Regards,... Fred

BigBlueButton Developer

Comment: Thanks Fred,
I follow your instruction and i can see my recording in RecordingsBN ! 
But it seems all recordings of all class is showed here, that's make my user confuse! 
I just want each recording is showed in each class(if any) - by clicking on a class link (a BigBlueButtonBN link, not a RecordingsBN link).
Please help me!